# Streamlit Webcam doesn't work on Streamlit Cloud

Tags: python, webcam, streamlit, face-recognition, face

I want to use the streamlit-webrtc and it works perfectly fine on my local network but as soon as I start it on the streamlit cloud it opens a video frame and after pressing the start button it loads forever. Then it shows a black screen and closes again, but I don't get any error message.

My GitHub repo is [sophiaia04/blublub](https://github.com/sophiaia04/blublub/tree/master) and the main code (`age_gender.py`) is on the master branch.

I've added a `test.py` file to try out the webcam but it's the same problem. It works on the local network but not on the streamlit cloud, so the code is fine just not the webcam on streamlit cloud.